# Increase variable if one week has passed swift

Tags: swift

So like I want to allow my app to check if one week has passed, and if that is true, Increase a certain variable, while at the same time, checking if the user has opened the app in that one week. If the user hasn't opened the app in the one week that passed, the app sends a notification to the user to open the app.

I've thought of using NSTImer to do this but I'm worried that the timer would stop when the user closes the app

Is there a way for an iOS app to keep track of real-time without using NSTimer?

Comment: This will work with Calendar and NSNotificaiton.

Comment: @Kudos how do i implement Calender and NSNotification

Comment: I'm ok with creating a server, but can you refer me to a tutorial or smt on how to create a time server and make the app get the time from the server?

Comment: I recall doing something similar a long time ago, I used EKCalendar 
with EKReminder, EKAlarm and EKEventStore to setup some reminders in the calendar 
that would be activated at the desired date in the future.

Comment: @KiranLim If you are working in Swift you must know how to work with Calendar and Location Notifications.

Comment: Kiran, a good solution here would be to store a date in UserDefaults. On launch, check if this date is a week ago using Calendar and DateComponents. If it is, increment your thing, and store the new current date for UserDefaults and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

These are different issues:

> if one week has passed, and if that is true, Increase a certain variable

Store a UserDefault with the starting date. When you launch, check the value. And observe `significantTimeChangeNotification` to see date changes while the app is running. In either case, if a week has passed, update your variable and the UserDefault.

> If the user hasn't opened the app in the one week that passed, the app sends a notification to the user to open the app.

Completely separate issue. This is done by scheduling a LocalNotification periodically for 1 week in the future. Periodically (i.e. during app launch and `significantTimeChangeNotification`) reschedule it. When it fires, it will show your alert.